# Kendo value binding - change event cancels first click made on anything else bound by kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

Take the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kp2C9/269/

If you make a change to the first input field, then click on the second, the click applies the model change but does not focus on the second input field.

Why is this and how do i resolve it?

**//JS**

```
var ViewModel = {
    FirstName: "Test",
    LastName: "Test"
};

var viewModel = new kendo.observable(ViewModel);
kendo.bind(document.getElementById("Test"), viewModel);
```

**// HTML**

```
<div id="Test">
  <div data-template="template-test" data-bind="source: this">
  </div>
</div>

<script id="template-test" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <div>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: FirstName" />
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: LastName" />
    #= FirstName # #= LastName #
  </div>
</script>
```

**// DISCOVERY**

- https://jsfiddle.net/kp2C9/270/ : You can see that by removing the reference to `this`, the view is no longer updated but the underlying model is (see console.log)